# AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: tensorflow, opencv

When I run these lines of code i get this error

> AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'"

I don't seem to get around it.

```
import streamlit as st
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

def detect_mask(image):
    image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(image.read(), dtype='uint8'),1)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1.0, (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
    net.setInput(blob)
    detection = net.forward()
```

Comment: You have no `import` statements. We have no idea what the result of `image.read()` might be. And you have a superfluous apostrope in `cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have added the statements.

Answer (score 0):

**Working sample code**

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

image ='image.jpeg'
with open(image, 'rb') as infile:
     buf = infile.read()

x = np.fromstring(buf, dtype='uint8')
img = cv2.imdecode(x, 1)
imag = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
(h, w) = imag.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(imag, 1.0, (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
```